# iIonic 4 ion-tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Hello every one i need your help! hope you can
i want to set the tabs2 as active when i open the app

i’m using ionic 4

here is my code

i do select("tab2) but its not working

```html
<ion-tabs selected="feed">
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="feed">
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="reported">
      <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: post your ts file

Comment: i want only to get the reported tab to be active not the feed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `selected` in `ion-tab-button` which you want to be selected.

In your case it will be like :

```html
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="feed" selected>
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="reported">
      <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```